# How to get back to GUI mode from init 3 Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This problem is pretty simple but here it is -

after you enter `init 3` how do you get back to GUI mode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`init <number>`, or actually `telinit <number>`, switches [*runlevels,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) which are basically just service groups. It stops services belonging to the old runlevel and starts those belonging to the new one.

In most Linux distributions which use this system, runlevel **5** is the "graphical interface" mode – the main difference is simply that it also starts the "display manager" service that shows the graphical login screen, usually gdm (or sddm, xdm) – so use **`init 5`** to activate it.

Recent Ubuntu versions do not use this system anymore. The commands still work but they're mapped to "targets" in systemd – runlevel 3 is `multi-user.target` and 5 is `graphical.target`. Those can be restarted much like individual services, using systemctl.

This means you should use **`systemctl restart graphical.target`** on recent (systemd-based) Ubuntu versions. (If that didn't work, try "isolate" instead of "restart".)